# preserving problem

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Define: $$\begin{align*}
\varphi &:L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1], \\ &(\varphi f)(x)=‎\int_0^x f(t)dt. 
\end{align*}‎$$

Is it true that, if ‎‎$‎‎B$ is a dense ‎subset ‎of ‎‎$‎‎L^2[0,1]$, then  ‎$‎‎\varphi(B)$ ‎is dense in $‎‎L^2[0,1]$?

Comment: Do you want capital L?

Comment: Yes, it was Typographical error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of the Volterra operator consists of all absolutely continuous functions vanishing at $0$. These are $L^2$-dense.

This also implies the (seemingly) stronger statement you gave.

Comment: why all absolutely continuous functions vanishing at 0  are L2-dense?

Comment: You can easily write down a dense set of bump functions.

Comment: who do we make this set?